# ENGL Screamer Tubes

Tags: amplifiers

I recently bought an ENGLScreamer 50W combo and I noticed that only two tubes (out of the six) are lit (the two big front ones if you look from the back). From the [manual](http://www.englamps.de/uploads/tx_ddfproducts/OM_E330_Screamer_50_Combo_E335_Screamer_Head.pdf) (page 5 at the bottom) I see that there are total of six tubes (V1-V6) and as I mentioned only V5 and V6 are lit.

Just wondered if this is how it is supposed to be or maybe some of them are damaged. (When I play the overall sound is great but just wanted to make sure I dont miss something here)

BTW I have noticed that the clean channel is much louder than the lead channel (master level is the same for both). Is that common as well ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think only V5 and V6 should look lit up as they are your power amp tubes.

From the manual, V1 to V4 are your preamp tubes - these don't draw anything like the current your power tubes will draw.

This is quite common.

The difference between clean and lead channels is likely to be down to the settings: Your foot pedal allows you to select between

- Clean (Clean & Lo Gain)
- Crunch (Clean & Hi Gain)
- Soft Lead (Lead & Lo Gain)
- Heavy Lead (Lead & Hi Gain)

So my guess is that you are currently selecting between Crunch and Soft Lead.

Comment: Thanks! Thats the answer I was hoping to get :). About the volume differences I though it might be caused by the tubes (if one was indeed damaged) but I guess it is just the balance between these channels. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

You can balance the levels between channels by adjusting the gain or vol controls for each while leaving the master alone. Since channel switching amps usually have a couple "volume(gain)" controls per channel, it's not uncommon to have volume differences.